# Why do OpenCV VideoWriter only support 8-bit depth images?

Tags: opencv

I use `VideoWriter::write` to wrote a `Mat` with the pixel format of `CV_32FC3`,but it would always cause an error when `VideoWriter::write` was called.

Then i found that any pixel format of `CV_8UC*` would always succeed.

But Why?

Error Msg Was:

`OpenCV(4.2.0) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray::create, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1195`

Any answer will be helpful

Comment: What format video file were you hoping to store your 96-bit video in? I mean which file extension were you expecting it to have?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i use mp4 as file extension.and do you mean that mp4 doesn't support it or something?

Comment: Correct, video is simply not stored at such high colour depths.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I got it, thank you very much

Comment: Since OpenCV 4.7.0 it is possible to write `CV_16UC1` videos, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76509662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

video is simply not stored at such high colour depths

Quoted From @MarkSetchell