# How to properly use OpenCV VideoWriter to write monochrome video with float32 source data type in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, kinect-v2, color-depth

I am trying to store video file from multiple sources (color, depth, and infrared) from Kinect sensors.

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCSMr.png) that I visualized using cv2.imshow command
using the following code:

```py
cv2.imshow("ir", ir / 65535.)
cv2.imshow("depth", depth / 4500.)
cv2.imshow("color", color)
```

IR and depth both are array with size of `(height, width)`, `float32`. Color is an array with size of `(height, width, 3)`, where 3 is the RGB channel and `uint8` type from 0-255. Since IR and depth's values are large, we need to normalize them using the code above. This code gave the above figures.

Now I want to store a series of image array as a video file. I use the following code:

```py
ir_video = cv2.VideoWriter('ir.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42'), fps, (height, width), False)
depth_video = cv2.VideoWriter('depth.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42'), fps, (height, width), False)
color_video = cv2.VideoWriter('color.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42'), fps, (height, width), True)

for ir, depth, color in zip(ir_frames, depth_frames, color_frames):
    ir_video.write(ir / 65535.)
    depth_video.write(depth / 4500.)
    color_video.write(color)

ir_video.release()
depth_video.release()
color_video.release()
```

Color video works very well, looks very similar to the `cv2.imshow` command. However, IR and depth video are corrupted. All 0kb.
I tried to change the fourcc code to `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`. This time the IR one saved a video that I can play. But it is very different from the `cv2.imshow` result. It is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr9Ec.jpg).

I'm wondering how I can correctly save the result as with `cv2.imshow` command. What fourcc code should be used? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read imshow and videowriter docs. Afair imshow expects floating points to be black <= 0 and white >= 1, while VideoWriter interpretes floats as black <= 0 and white >= 255.0

Comment: You may convert to `uint8` in range [0, 255] before saving: Example instead of writing: `depth / 4500.`, write: `(depth * (255.0/4500.0)).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Thanks you@Micka for explaining.

Comment: Thanks a lot@Rotem. Your solution is perfect yet simple! Works now!

Comment: @Rotem I'm wondering after saving the video, how can I revert it back to 'depth' value? Now when I read the saved depth video using the command, it return me a (height, width,3) array. How do I revert it back to the (height, width) float array? The calculation part is clear I just need to do the math inversion of '(depth * (255.0/4500.0)).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)', but how about from 3 channels to one? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok. Figure it out. data = double(rgb2gray(frame))/(255/4500); Convert it back to double first is very important.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with OpenCV 4.7.0 it is possible to write 16-bit depth videos, see the [pull request which added support for it](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22894).

For `VideoWriter` you have to:

- specify `CAP_FFMPEG` because this only seems to be supported for FFmpeg at the moment
- use the `FFV1` codec
- specify `{VIDEOWRITER_PROP_DEPTH, CV_16U, VIDEOWRITER_PROP_IS_COLOR, false}` as *params*

For `VideoCapture` (reading) you have to:

- specify `CAP_FFMPEG`
- specify `{CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, false}` as *params*
  Note that this will print a warning like "VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: BGR conversion turned OFF ..." to the console.

There appear to be some limitations with this though, see the [description of the pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22894#issue-1470329314).

That pull request also added a unit test [which contains a `VideoWriter` & `VideoCapture` round trip](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f2f00259dae07c9b6969d70e2e1a3024e3f2a09c/modules/videoio/test/test_ffmpeg.cpp#L548-L627).

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided in the question comments converts the image data from `float32` to `uint8` which is sufficient to save the video properly. However, a lot of information is lost due to `uint8` only being able to represent 256 values. That is also the reason why the source data (IR and depth) are `float32` and not `uint8` as with the color images - a lot of information would be lost when saved as `uint8`. Therefore, I propose a solution that saves the video in `uint16` format with the `VideoWriter` used by the author of the question.

At first, it is necessary to convert the values from `float32` to `uint16` (range 0-65,535). According to author's code, IR image seems to already fall in that range, so only casting to `uint16` is necessary. However, depth image has to be normalized from its original range 0-4,500 to the `uint16` range. This code should be placed in the for loop provided by author before the `write` method.

```py
ir = ir.astype(np.uint16)
depth = (depth * (65_535.0 / 4500.0)).astype(np.uint16)
```

@Marcono1234 [provided an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76509662/11441775) how to save video with `OpenCV` [VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#aff57b7ffbd654ef2f83e7ad76916426b) (since version 4.7.0) but didn't provide the Python code. I find it not trivial to program it correctly, so I provide a fully working example of reading an image from your webcam, converting it to monochrome image 16 bits of depth and saving it as such. Run to record the video and use keyboard letter `q` to stop recording. The most important part is obviously the VideoWriter definition.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not video_capture.isOpened():
    print("Error reading video file")

video_width = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
video_height = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
    filename="video.mkv",
    apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,
    fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"FFV1"),
    fps=10.0,
    frameSize=(video_width, video_height),
    params=[
        cv2.VIDEOWRITER_PROP_DEPTH,
        cv2.CV_16U,
        cv2.VIDEOWRITER_PROP_IS_COLOR,
        0,  # false
    ],
)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret:
        # Convert the webcam image to mono 16-bit.
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame = frame.astype(np.uint16)
        frame *= 2 ** 8

        video_writer.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

video_capture.release()
video_writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To make the example complete, you'd also like to read the video somehow. Here's again a fully working example of `OpenCV` [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a31e7cf5ba9debaec15437a200b18241e) with monochrome 16-bit depth video.

```py
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(
    filename="video.mkv",
    apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,
    params=[
        cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB,
        0,  # false
    ],
)

if not video_capture.isOpened():
    print("Error reading video file")

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Be aware that produced video might not be playable with every video player since `FFV1` encoding of 16-bit depth mono video is not so common yet. `VLC media player` had this [discussed](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/27235) and supports it [since version 3.0.18](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/merge_requests/2446) and some improvements might also [come in version 4.0](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/merge_requests/2459) when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project using other depth cameras (Orbbec, Asus Xtion) and afaik videowriter class of OpenCV does not support 16-bit depth images, that's why as suggested in the comments you should convert to 8 bit. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/danielelic/PyOpenNI2-Utility/blob/58247c409afa009a7bae4e211b3d6c72f15ac551/oni2avi.py#L45) for what I was using to save such a video (It's about using OpenNI2 but the main concept is there).